# Run Wifi (Intel AX210) with Single Antenna

Tags: wireless, wifi, linux, wifi-direct

NOTE - this was originally [asked at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1796139/run-wifi-intel-ax210-with-single-antenna), but they suggested I ask it here.

Is it possible to run an Intel AX210 chip using a single antenna? I've got an embedded project where a single antenna would be optimal. With a single antenna, I get almost perfect data connectivity, but the connection is failing because, I think, the chip is only sending Wifi Beacons out of one antenna at a time, and it isn't always the one I'm using!

The device connecting to it is repeatedly disconnecting due to beacon loss in a single-antenna configuration.

I'm assuming that this is some artifact of MIMO. Is there any way to disable MIMO on these devices? I'm on Linux using the iwlwifi driver, but I'm not seeing any option to disable MIMO, either in the driver parameters or in the wpa_supplicant config file. I'm running Linux 5.15.32.

Comment: You can use a power combiner (hardware), work in 802.11n mode and/or disable any MIMO functionality in the driver (It is possible to do it in Windows, I don't know about Linux).

Comment: @LiorBilia - I couldn't find an option to disable MIMO.

Comment: @LiorBilia - I'll go look at power combiners. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Depending on your location, you can check Minicircuts, Pasternack or Radiall.